# Analyzer not found exception while creating an index with mapping and settings

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Hi I am using Elastic Search elasticsearch-0.90.2 version. I am trying to map analyzer with custom analyzer using jsonBuilder, while creating index, it is throwing exception like analyzer not found.

Setting :-

```
       XContentBuilder settings = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
            .startObject()
                 .startObject("settings")
                      .startObject("analysis")
                           .startObject("analyzer")                 
                                .startObject("search_analyzer")             
                                      .field("tokenizer", "ngram_specification")
                                      .field("type", "custom")
                                      .field("filter", new String[]{ "ngram_specification"})
                                .endObject()
                            .endObject()
                            .startObject("ngram_specification")
                                 .field("type", "nGram")
                                 .field("min_gram", "2")
                                 .field("max_gram", "5")
                            .endObject()    
                      .endObject()
                 .endObject()
            .endObject();
```

Mapping :-

```
  XContentBuilder mapping = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()

      .startObject()
             .startObject("sample")
                 .startObject("properties")
                     .startObject("email").field("type", "string").field("index", "analyzed").field("analyzer", "search_analyzer")
                     .endObject()
                 .endObject()
            .endObject()
      .endObject();
```

Creating Index like this :-

```
        CreateIndexRequest indexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(indexName);
        indexRequest.settings(settings);
        indexRequest.mapping("sample", mapping);
        CreateIndexResponse response = client.admin().indices().create(indexRequest).actionGet();
```

Exception :

```
    17:00:52,767 ERROR [STDERR] org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: mapping [3]
    17:00:52,767 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService$1.execute(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:289)
    17:00:52,767 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$2.run(InternalClusterService.java:229)
    17:00:52,767 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:95)
    17:00:52,767 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    17:00:52,767 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    17:00:52,767 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    17:00:52,767 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Analyzer [search_analyzer] not found for field [email]
    17:00:52,767 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.TypeParsers.parseField(TypeParsers.java:100)
    17:00:52,767 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.StringFieldMapper$TypeParser.parse(StringFieldMapper.java:151)
    17:00:52,767 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseProperties(ObjectMapper.java:263)
    17:00:52,767 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parse(ObjectMapper.java:219)
    17:00:52,767 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:176)
    17:00:52,767 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:380)
    17:00:52,767 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.merge(MapperService.java:190)
    17:00:52,767 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService$1.execute(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:286)]
```

Can anyone please tell the mistake in this approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution for this. In Settings, if you use "index" instead of "Settings" then it will work fine.

This is wrong:

```
XContentBuilder settings = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
    .startObject()
         .startObject("settings") // "settings"
              .startObject("analysis")
```

but this *does*:

```
XContentBuilder settings = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
    .startObject()
         .startObject("index") // "index" instead of "settings"
              .startObject("analysis")
```

Comment: refer to https://github.com/dadoonet/spring-elasticsearch/issues/12 why use index instead of settings ?

Answer (score 2):

You can check if your settings are correctly applied using the [Get Settings API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-get-settings/).

I think you analyzer has not been created because of an error in your settings configuration. The `tokenizer` entry is probably missing. Here is a corrected version :

```
  XContentBuilder settings = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
        .startObject()
             .startObject("settings")
                  .startObject("analysis")
                       .startObject("analyzer")                 
                            .startObject("search_analyzer")             
                                  .field("tokenizer", "ngram_specification")
                                  .field("type", "custom")
                                  .field("filter", new String[]{ "ngram_specification"})
                            .endObject()
                        .endObject()
                        .startObject("tokenizer")
                             .startObject("ngram_specification")
                                  .field("type", "nGram")
                                  .field("min_gram", "2")
                                  .field("max_gram", "5")
                             .endObject()    
                        .endObject()    
                  .endObject()
             .endObject()
        .endObject();
```

Comment: Good one! At first glance I think the filter is missing too.

Comment: i did changes mentioned here. still getting same error analyzer not found. :(