# Error while creating an index on Elasticsearch with custom analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am trying to create an index with a custom default analyzer.
I already checked the following questions:

- [Analyzer not found exception while creating an index with mapping and settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569938/analyzer-not-found-exception-while-creating-an-index-with-mapping-and-settings)
- [How to specify an analyzer while creating an index in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237817/how-to-specify-an-analyzer-while-creating-an-index-in-elasticsearch)
- [mapper_parsing_exception for a custom analyzer while creating index in elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35731835/mapper-parsing-exception-for-a-custom-analyzer-while-creating-index-in-elasticse)

but they didn't solve the issue.

Here is my schema:

```
put /emails
{
   "mappings": {
      "email": {
         "analyzer": "lkw",
         "properties": {
            "createdOn": {
               "type": "date",
               "store": true,
               "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
            },
            "data": {
               "type": "object",
               "dynamic": "true"
            },
            "from": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true
            },
            "id": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true
            },
            "sentOn": {
               "type": "date",
               "store": true,
               "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
            },
            "sesId": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true
            },
            "subject": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true,
               "analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "templates": {
               "properties": {
                  "html": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "store": true
                  },
                  "plainText": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "store": true
                  }
               }
            },
            "to": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true
            },
            "type": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true
            }
         }
      },
      "event": {
         "_parent": {
            "type": "email"
         },
         "analyzer": "lkw",
         "properties": {
            "id": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true
            },
            "origin": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true
            },
            "time": {
               "type": "date",
               "store": true,
               "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
            },
            "type": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true
            },
            "userAgent": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "lkw": {
               "tokenizer": "keyword",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase"
               ],
               "type": "custom"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

When I execute the command above, I get this error:

```
{
       "error": {
          "root_cause": [
             {
                "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [analyzer : lkw]"
             }
          ],
          "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
          "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [event]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [analyzer : lkw]",
          "caused_by": {
             "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
             "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [analyzer : lkw]"
          }
       },
       "status": 400
    }
```

Comment: Do you want your `lkw` analyzer to be applied to all `string` fields which don't have a specific analyzer?

Comment: Yes, that was the idea

Comment: Since you have only a few string fields, why not simply specifying your `lkw` analyzer where you need it, just like you did for the `standard` one?

Comment: I tried. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have only a few string fields, I suggest you simply specify your `lkw` analyzer where you need it, just like you did for the `standard` one:

```
PUT /emails
{
   "mappings": {
      "email": {
         "properties": {
            "createdOn": {
               "type": "date",
               "store": true,
               "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
            },
            "data": {
               "type": "object",
               "dynamic": "true"
            },
            "from": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true,
               "analyzer": "lkw"
            },
            "id": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true,
               "analyzer": "lkw"
            },
            "sentOn": {
               "type": "date",
               "store": true,
               "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
            },
            "sesId": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true,
               "analyzer": "lkw"
            },
            "subject": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true,
               "analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "templates": {
               "properties": {
                  "html": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "store": true,
                     "analyzer": "lkw"
                  },
                  "plainText": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "store": true,
                     "analyzer": "lkw"
                  }
               }
            },
            "to": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true,
               "analyzer": "lkw"
            },
            "type": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true,
               "analyzer": "lkw"
            }
         }
      },
      "event": {
         "_parent": {
            "type": "email"
         },
         "properties": {
            "id": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true,
               "analyzer": "lkw"
            },
            "origin": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true,
               "analyzer": "lkw"
            },
            "time": {
               "type": "date",
               "store": true,
               "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
            },
            "type": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true,
               "analyzer": "lkw"
            },
            "userAgent": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true,
               "analyzer": "lkw"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "lkw": {
               "tokenizer": "keyword",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase"
               ],
               "type": "custom"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'll take this as the correct answer. Do you know why the other way is not working?

Comment: Because that was not a correct way of specifying an analyzer to be used for a field.

Comment: Trying to understand what I did wrong because I set the default analyzer on other indexes.

Comment: You simply need to call it `default` in your index settings for it to work.

Comment: I found out it was a breaking change 1.x => 2.x
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html#_analyzer_mappings
Thanks for your help!